# Is there a "Tool" to convert WCF XAML based Activities to CodeActivity

Tags: wcf, xaml

I have bunch(100's?) of XAML (Designer) Acitvities That would like to be AutoMagically  converted to CodeActivities.

Reasons?, Too many.. (it makes me angry?)

I've .., of course been moving them one by one to CodeActivities, fairly easy, but time consuming.

So.. the question again ..
Is there a tool that can do this for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, there is no such tool at the time of writing this ...